# Pass JOBID from SQL Job Agent to project parameter fails "Failed to configure an overridden property"

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent

I've been able to map a token from SQL Job Agent to a user variable in SSIS with this approach:

[image: SQL Agent mapping]

If the picture can't be seen: I've edited the job step in SQL Job Agent under Configuration -> Advanced to have Property Path \Package.Variables[User::SQLAgent_JobID].Value and Property Value $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID)).

This works, but I'm intending to do this for a project variable with the same name but I receive the error "Failed to configure an overridden property" doing this.

I've tried different Property Paths like:

```
Project.params[SQLAgent_JobID].Value
\Project.params[SQLAgent_JobID].Value
\Package.Variables[Project::SQLAgent_JobID].Value
\Package.Variables[$Project::SQLAgent_JobID].Value
```

but the error persists. Does anyone know the Property Path syntax needed to map a token to a project parameter (if it is possible?)?

Comment: That's not setting a parameter, you're overring a property. There's a specific pane for parameters.

Comment: Though, why do you want to set a project parameter? If you are wanting to change a project parameter at run time, it should probably *not* be a project parameter and should be a package parameter; or you should be setting up environments (within SSISDB).

Comment: @ThomA         Thanks, I'll look into that! The reasonining behind using a project parameter is simply because I have a Master package which I run using SQL Agent which calls several child packages. The JobID is used for logging and I'm trying to avoid having to go into each package and add a package variable.

Comment: Hmm, does sound like environments might be what you want here. I openly admit I haven't used environments in a while (years) after we changed our server and deployment structure at the office, so as much as I likely *could* post as answer, I wouldn't trust it to be accurate.

Comment: @ThomA         Feel free to post your comment about the parameter pane so I can accept it. I didn't think I could write expressions there, but for some reason having $ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID)) as the value of the Master package's package variable made it work.